# Heatweighting issue - Can't resolve it (armature) TOO MANY VERTICES

Tags: animation, modifiers, armature, bones, vertices

I'm kinda desperate here. I had a project due tonight and I can't animate this teddy bear. I have over a million vertices and I have no idea how. I already tried to remove the doubles, did the boolean modifier for the meshes that were overlapping... I did the bone structure x10 times to see if that was it... I don't get it. I can't remove more vertices and I can't animate it... I'm really desperate by now. Can someone help me please?

Ps- As you can tell I'm awfull at 3D (and it's a shame because I see a lot of you doing great stuff)... But I have no choice if I want to finish college.....

LINK FOR THE FILE [HERE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wj_0qrXkeA9Viq2s9KmrZEmTT4KV_0pS?usp=sharing)

[image: the character]

[image: can't even do the boolean with the ears]

Comment: Try using the decimate modifier to reduce the number of vertices in your model. you should probably aim for around 50000-250000 vertices. If the decimation damages the surface too badly us the remesh modifier. Good luck with your project ad I hope I helped

Comment: maybe share your file so we can test the best method: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You could use ctrl E > Un-Subdivide on the high-poly parts and play with the iteration value (on the bottom of the T panel on the left of the 3D view), but I wonder why don't simply redo your mesh which is very simple. If you want it smooth use a Subdivision Surface modifier. Unless you need to export it for a certain purpose and can't use any modifier?